# Двусоставные неполные или односоставные придаточные?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика

Помогите определить односоставные или двусоставные придаточные представленные в этом предложении.

> *Если бы не предупредил тебя, тебе, пожалуй, показалось бы, что повесть написана художественно, что у автора много поэтического
>   таланта.*

1) *Если бы не предупредил тебя*... - пропущено подлежащее выраженное местоимением ***я***, но оно восстанавливается из ситуации - значит предложение двусоставное неполное(ситуативное)?

2)... *тебе, пожалуй, показалось бы* - нет подлежащего, и оно по идее не требуется. А какой тип тогда?

3)...*что у автора много поэтического таланта* - здесь вообще не получается определить главные члены предложения :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)Если бы не предупредил тебя, (2) тебе, пожалуй, показалось бы, (3) что  повесть написана художественно, (4) что у автора много поэтического таланта

1. Неполное двусоставное.
2. Односоставное безличное: восприятие и мыслительные процессы (показалось, послышалось, вспомнилось).
3. Двусоставное.
4. Очень проблемный вид предложения, можно отнести к двусоставным предложениям эллиптическим вида "дополнение - количественный оборот".

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду,что тут пропущено слово **"есть/имеется"** которое может выступать сказуемым? _"У автора **имеется** много поэтического таланта"_  Но где подлежащее? Оно вроде не требуется... Может это **односоставное неполное** предложение?

Comment: Подлежащее - количественный оборот "много таланта". В неполном предложении пропущенный член восстанавливается по контексту, а в этом случае не требуется контекст, чтобы восстановить сказуемое. Под это условие подходят эллиптические предложения с нулевым сказуемым, на место которого подходят разные варианты (есть, имеется).

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Просто не сталкивалась с понятием "количественного оборота". А **"много"** в этом обороте выступает скорее как **наречие** чем числительное, верно?

Comment: Две книги, много книг - это примеры числовых (количественных) оборотов и количественно-именных сочетаний. В предложении такой оборот рассматривается как единый член.